# Getting the first digit of a number within a variable

Tags: macros

I have a custom macro like this that stores data:

```
\somecommand{some text}{234}
```

Inside the `newcommand` for this, I can access the second column of data using `#2`.

- How can I obtain the first digit of that number? For e.g.:

`\somecommand{some text}{3012}` gives `3`

`\somecommand{some text}{21231}` gives `2`

`\somecommand{some text}{9}` gives `9`

Comment: What does `\somecommand` look like, since `\somecommand` does not have a `#3` argument?

Comment: Oh, I made an error while writing it, I will fix that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `\StrLeft` from the [xstring](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\somecommand[2]{%
  \StrLeft{#2}{1}}
\begin{document}

\somecommand{some text}{3012}

\somecommand{some text}{21231}

\somecommand{some text}{9}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach using TeX programming would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\somecommand}[2]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
    {\GetFirstDigit#2\stop}%
}
\makeatother
\def\GetFirstDigit#1#2\stop{#1}
```

where `\stop` is 'something that will not appear in `#2`'.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution without `xstring` (but tricky):

```
\def\helper#1{\let\temp#1\iffalse}
\newcommand\somecommand[2]{%
  \helper#2\fi
  \temp}
```

---

Joseph Wright pointed that it may fail if `#2` is empty. However, it does work.

When we use `\somecommand{foo}{}`, we have

```
#1->foo
#2->(empty)
```

Then `\somecommand{foo}{}` expands to

```
\helper\fi
\temp
```

And then, `\helper\fi` expands to

```
\let\temp\fi\iffalse
```

So we have

```
\let\temp\fi\iffalse
\temp
```

Thus

```
\iffalse\fi
```

---

Anyway, Joseph's solution is better. My `\somecommand` is not expandable, it may fail in a `\edef`.

Comment: Runs away if `#2` is completely empty.

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm sorry I didn't realized that case. However, `\somecommand{foo}{}` does works. `\temp` will be `\fi` (I don't know why) then `\somecommand{foo}{}` becomes `\iffalse\temp` and then `\iffalse\fi`. I;ll be glad if you can explain this. Maybe I'll post another question.

Comment: OK, I understand it now. I'll add some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify, if you wish using a  macro with delimited parameters `\def`:

```
\def\somecommand #1|#2#3|{%
  #2
}
\somecommand Plenty of text|1234567|
```

I use `|` as a marker, but you can use anything you like. If there is no chance of a semicolon in the text, I would use a semicolon. This type of macro definition was quite a favourite with Knuth and there are many examples in the TeXbook. If the text is longer than a paragraph use `\long\def`.